# How to generate combination of numbers in more optimized way in Java?

Tags: java, numbers, combinations, triplet

I had a problem statement which requires passing 3 different numbers to a method and checking which 3 numbers satisfies a certain constraint.

Here is my code, but I wanted to know instead of creating nested loops, is there any more optimized way of checking which set of triplet satisfies a certain constraint. ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution
{

    static List l = new ArrayList();

    static int geometricTrick(String s)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++)
                {
                    if (is1stConstraintTrue(s, i, j, k) && is2ndConstraintTrue(i, j, k))
                    {
                        l.add(new Triplet(i, j, k));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        count = l.size();

        return count;

    }

    static boolean is2ndConstraintTrue(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        boolean retVal = false;

        double LHS = Math.pow((j + 1), 2);

        double RHS = (i + 1) * (k + 1);

        if (LHS == RHS)
            retVal = true;
        else
            retVal = false;

        return retVal;
    }

    static boolean is1stConstraintTrue(String s, int i, int j, int k)
    {
        boolean retVal = false;

        char[] localChar = s.toCharArray();

        if (localChar[i] == 'a' && localChar[j] == 'b' && localChar[k] == 'c')
        {
            retVal = true;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    static class Triplet
    {
        public int i, j, k;

        public Triplet(int i, int j, int k)
        {
            this.i= i;
            this.j= j;
            this.k= k;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String s = in.next();
        int result = geometricTrick(s);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your satisfaction criteria ?

Comment: `double` comparison is not good. Change it back to `int`.

Comment: this looks like a twofolded problem. First you look for the characters `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`  in your input. Next you want to know whether the indices at which the characters stand satisfy some condition. Instead of iterating over the whole `String` and checking each triplet, I would first look for all occurences of `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` and then test only these triplets.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

1. Computing the square by multiplication will be faster than using `pow`
2. `String::toCharray()` is expensive.  It copies all characters into a new array.  Each time you call it.  Don't call it multiple times.
3. If the result is the number of triples, you don't need to build a list.  You don't even need to create `Triple` instances.  Just count them.
4. Nested loops are not inefficient, if you *need* to iterate all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

To provide you a simple and "stupid" solution to not use those inner loops.

Let's use a Factory like an `Iterator`. This would "hide" the loop by using condition statement.

```
public class TripletFactory{

    final int maxI, maxJ, maxK;
    int i, j ,k;

    public TripletFactory(int i, int j, int k){
        this.maxI = i;
        this.maxJ = j;
        this.maxK = k;
    }

    public Triplet next(){
        if(++k > maxK){
            k = 0;
            if(++j > maxJ){
                j = 0;
                if(++i > maxI){
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return new Triplet(i,j,k);
    }
}
```

That way, you just have to get a new `Triple` until a `null` instance in ONE loop

```
TripletFactory fact = new TripletFactory(2, 3 ,5);

Triplet t = null;
while((t = fact.next()) != null){
    System.out.println(t);
}
//no more Triplet
```

And use it like you want.

Then, you will have to update your constraint method to take a `Triplet` and use the getters to check the instance.

That could be a method of `Triplet` to let it validate itself by the way.

Note :

I used the same notation as the `Iterator` because we could implement `Iterator` and `Iterable` to use a notation like :

```
for(Triplet t : factory){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach you presented has cubic time complexity (three nested `for`-loops). If you have many occurrences of `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` within your input, it may be worth wile to first determine the indices of all `'a'`'s, `'b'`'s and `'c'`'s and then check your second condition only over this set.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static List<Integer> getAllOccurrences(String input, char of) {
        List<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();

        for (int idx = 0; idx < chars.length; ++idx) {
            if (of == chars[idx]) {
                occurrences.add(idx);
            }
        }

        return (occurrences);
    }

    static List<Triplet> geometricTrick(String input){
        List<Integer> allAs = getAllOccurrences(input, 'a');
        List<Integer> allBs = getAllOccurrences(input, 'b');
        List<Integer> allCs = getAllOccurrences(input, 'c');
        List<Triplet> solutions = new ArrayList<Triplet>();

        // reorder the loops, so that the c-loop is the innermost loop (see
        // below why this is useful and how it is exploited).
        for (int a : allAs) {
            for (int c : allCs) {
                // calculate lhs as soon as possible, no need to recalculate the
                // same value multiple times
                final int lhs = ((a + 1) * (c + 1));

                for (int b : allBs) {
                    final int rhs = ((b + 1) * (b + 1));
                    if (lhs > rhs) {
                       continue;
                    }

                    /* else */ if (lhs == rhs) {
                        solutions.add(new Triplet(a, b, c));
                    }

                    // by construction, the b-values are in ascending or der.
                    // Thus if the rhs-value is larger or equal to the
                    // lhs-value, we can skip all other rhs-values. for this
                    // lhs-value.

                    // if (lhs <= rhs) {
                        break;
                    // }
                }
            }
        }
        return (solutions);
    }

    static class Triplet {

        public final int i;
        public final int j;
        public final int k;

        public Triplet(int i, int j, int k) {
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
            this.k = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Searching all occurrences of one `char` within a given `String` takes O(n) (method `getAllOccurrences(...)`), calling it three times does not change the complexity (3 * n \in O(n)). Iterating through all possible combinations of `a`, `b` and `c` takes #`a` * #`b` * #`c` time, where #`a`, #`b` and #`c` stay for the count of `a`'s, `b`'s and `c`'s in your `input`. This gives a total time complexity of O(n + #`a` * #`b` * #`c`).

Note that the worst case time complexity, i.e. if 1/3 of your string consists of `a`'s, 1/3 consists of `b`'s and 1/3 consists of `c`'s, is still cubic.